# VMware Player Guest VPN Connection Fails

Tags: centos, vpn, vmware-workstation

I have a laptop running CentOS that has VMware Workstation Player to run select Windows VMs. Said VMs likely have Dell's Global VPN Client installed on them for the cases where customers are using SonicWalls and require the software. The VM's network adapter is configured for bridging, and while Player doesn't let one specify which physical host adapter to bridge to, only the host's ethernet interface is enabled and has an active connection. The bridging appears to be successful since the VM can not only obtain a DHCP lease from our upstream DHCP server, but it can also access other network devices/services, and it can route outbound to the Internet. So far, so good.

When I attempt to establish a connection to one of our customers with the SonicWall GVC software, the program gets stuck at Acquiring IP, and it continuously loops on this phase. The credentials and shared keys are correct, and the remote VPN service is functional since other users on different workstations can connect. From the surface level, what I have noticed is that if this is done on a host running Windows, everything works fine, albeit a little rocky to start. When the host is the CentOS computer, it always fails. I really don't think this says anything at all, which is why I don't want to leave it here.

I'm unsure where to begin diagnosing. I've disabled firewalld and SELinux thinking that the issue might be with the host, but this didn't have any effect. I also changed from bridged to NAT to see if that might do anything, but again, no joy. Any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check which routes your VPN is advertising? It is possible there may be a conflict to the routing tables. Also, make sure Cisco VPN is running as administrator. Also, what does the log message say about what is happening?

Comment: @DavidO. The VPN is customer-owned. If there's a means for checking route advertisement externally, I'm unaware of it. The VPN Client is running as an administrator. The message log is too long to post, but Phase 1 ISAKMP connections claim that incoming ISAKMP packets are ignored, continues and completes Phase 2, attempts to renew the IP address for the VPN Virtual Interface on the guest, gets stuck on NAT KEEP ALIVE, evidently gives up, and restarts the process all over again. I'll see if I can truncate the logs and omit sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. It was determined that the fault lied with the GVC software itself rather than anything with the networking. The original software had been purged from the VM and reinstalled with fresh configurations.

Comment: I've found that just reinstalling will usually fix this issue, especially with Windows 10.